# Remove last character from line

Tags: text-processing

I want to remove last character from a line:

```
[root@ozzesh ~]#df -h | awk  '{ print $5 }'
Use%
22%
1%
1%
59%
51%
63%
5%
```

Expected result:

```
Use
22
1
1
59
51
63
5
```

Comment: Is it always a `%` sign?

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow: How to remove last n characters from a string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39013253/4561887)

Answer (score 151):

```
sed 's/.$//'
```

To remove the last character.

But in this specific case, you could also do:

```
df -P | awk 'NR > 1 {print $5+0}'
```

With the arithmetic expression (`$5+0`) we force `awk` to interpret the 5th field as a number, and anything after the number will be ignored.

Note that GNU `df` (your `-h` is already a GNU extension, though not needed here) can also be told to only output the disk usage percentage:

```
df --output=pcent | tail -n +2 | tr -cd '0-9\n'
```

(tail skips the headers and tr removes everything but the digits and the line delimiters).

On Linux, see also:

```
findmnt -no USE%
```

Comment: `{print +$5}` will work as well...

Comment: @jasonwryan, unfortunately, [there are a lot of `awk` implementations where that doesn't work](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11391), where the `+` unary operator is just ignored and doesn't force conversion of strings to numerical.

Comment: `sed 's/.$//'` removes everything for me

Answer (score 32):

With `sed`, this is pretty easy:

```
$ cat file
Use%
22%
1%
1%
59%
51%
63%
5%
$ sed 's/.$//' file
Use
22
1
1
59
51
63
5
```

The syntax is `s(ubstitute)/search/replacestring/`. The `.` indicates any character, and the `$` the end of the line. So `.$` will remove the last character only.

In this case, your complete command would look:

```
df -h | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: The pipe to `sed` is redundant: it can be done in `awk`: `df -h | awk '{gsub(/%/,""); print $5}'`

Comment: @jasonwryan Then I like Stephane's solution better.

Answer (score 26):

I have two solutions :

1. cut:  `echo "somestring1" | rev | cut -c 2- | rev`

   Here you reverse the string and cut the string from 2nd character and reverse again.
2. sed :  `echo "somestring1" | sed 's/.$//'`

   Here you will search for regular expression `.$` which means any characters followed by a last character and replace it with null `//` (between the two slashes)

Answer (score 11):

In awk, you could do one of

```
awk '{sub(/%$/,"",$5); print $5}'
awk '{print substr($5, 1, length($5)-1)}'
```

Answer (score 7):

Did you know that `head` and `tail` can work on a character basis instead of per line?

```
$ printf "I don't like periods." | head -c-1
I don't like periods
```

(BTW, `printf` is used here to prevent printing the "new line" character at the end of the line. If your output has a new line character and you want to remove that as well as the last non-whitespace character, use `head -c-2`).

This is basically the same as "Guru"'s solution using `cut`, but without the funky `rev` back and forth that they need to use because `cut` has no syntax for "last n things".

To iterate over a stream of lines and remove the last character of each, one might do something like this:

```
some-command | while read line; do echo $(head -c-2 <<<"$line"); done
```

Comment: This will remove the last character of a file, not the last character of every line.

Comment: Got it, easy to fix. gimme a minute...

Comment: should we do `&& echo ""` in order to get rid of EOF char that might be printed out

Comment: @alper - when you say "get rid of EOF" you mean "add missing EOL"? If so, and you mean in the first example, then yes - `echo ""` prints out an zero-length string, after which the echo implementation auto-adds `\n` (which the `printf` in my example didn't on purpose, as is explained in the BTW).

Comment: @alper - that being said, if you want to mimic the auto-newline `echo` behavior, I prefer to use it by having `echo` actually print the entire thing - as I demonstrated in the second example.

Comment: @Guss I don't know the term but I keep seeing a character (`%`) so when I do `echo ""` that character is gone

Answer (score 4):

```
df -h | awk 'NR > 1{ print $5 }' | cut -d "%" -f1
```

Comment: This answer could be more helpful to others beyond OP if you could provide a bit of explanation regarding how it works and possibly why this might be better than the alternatives

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how this site works.  When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one the reader wants.  This means it is best if you give some explanation of how it works.  If you look above, you will see that all of the highly voted answers explain the code.

Comment: Upvoted for the use of `cut -d '%' -f1` which is the correct answer to get everything in the line up to the first '%'.

Comment: Plus I believe only harmful / wrong answers should ever get downvoted below 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "123" | perl -ple 'chop'
12
```

Comment: Honestly, this one is the most human-readable, which will always get my vote.

Comment: The only issue is it won't remove a newline character :(

Comment: @thekingoftruth, it works fine for me! ( `-l` already removes the newline, `chop` removes next char)

Answer (score 2):

another approach:

```
mapfile -t list < <(df -h)
printf '%s\n' "${list[@]%?}"
```

Turn it into a function:

```
remove_last() {
  local char=${1:-?}; shift
  mapfile -t list < <("$@")
  printf '%s\n' "${list[@]%$char}"
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
remove_last '%' df -h
```

`mapfile` is a bash4 feature.

The catch here is that you **must** supply a character to remove; if you want it to just be *whatever the last character happens to be* then you must pass `'?'` or `''`. quotes required.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ df -h | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
df -h | awk  '{ print $5 }' | sed "s/%//"
```

The normal use is:
(ie)

```
VALUE=987654321
echo X123456789X | sed "s/123456789/${VALUE}/"
```

Response should be: X987654321X

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ie '$d' filename

here -i is to write changes
      e means expression
      $ means last line
      d means delete

Note:Without -e option $ wont work
```

*Optional*: To delete 1st and last line use `sed -ie '1d;$d'` filename