# Grep for dates older than 14 days in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I'm trying to find a way to grep how many messages in a file are older than `14 days` and have a value of number of results return

Example going with today's date of `20160616`. `$grep 'Put Date' filename`:

```
Put Date     :'20160425'
Put Date     :'20160501'
Put Date     :'20160514'
Put Date     :'20160609'
Put Date     :'20160610'
Put Date     :'20160616'
```

The results should see the following are older than 14 days and would `return 3` :

```
Put Date     :'20160226'
Put Date     :'20160501'
Put Date     :'20160514'
```

Comment: I removed the blank lines between each of the lines in your input. I assume you had only added them for clarity. If they are actually part of your file please replace them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
awk -v threshold=$(date "--date=$(date) -14 day" +%Y%m%d) -F "'" '$2 < threshold' filename | wc -l
```

This is similar to the solution in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134593/173282) except that the date is computed inline.

**Note:** `filename` should be replaced by the name of *your file*.

Also, remember to be careful with your rules for boundary dates (check the edge conditions).

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution was posted, so I'll do a `grep`-based one.

First, create a file with dates that you don't want to see, one per line. This will only be 15 entries, so it's not much processing needed and is quick. The following requires GNU `date`, which on my [BSD] system is installed as `gdate`:

```
i=0
while (( i < 15 )); do
    gdate -d "now -$(( i++ )) days" +"%Y%m%d"
done >dates_to_skip
```

Once that's done, you can simply use that as the filter for `fgrep -v`:

```
fgrep -v -f dates_to_skip mydata
```